# Replace rows in an MxN matrix with numbers from 1 to N

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, row

Im interested in replacing all of my rows in an MxN matrix with values from 1 to N.

For example:
[[4,6,8,9,3],[5,1,2,5,6],[1,9,4,5,7],[3,8,8,2,5],[1,4,2,2,7]]

To:
[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]

I've tried using loops going through each row individually but struggle to replace elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    [4, 6, 8, 9, 3],
    [5, 1, 2, 5, 6],
    [1, 9, 4, 5, 7],
    [3, 8, 8, 2, 5],
    [1, 4, 2, 2, 7],
]

for row in lst:
    row[:] = range(1, len(row) + 1)

print(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged your question with *numpy*, I assume that your source array
is a **Numpy** array.

So, for the test purpose, you can create it as:

```
arr = np.array([[4,6,8,9,3],[5,1,2,5,6],[1,9,4,5,7],[3,8,8,2,5],[1,4,2,2,7]])
```

Then, to fill each row with consecutive numbers, you can run:

```
arr[:] = np.arange(1, arr.shape[1] + 1)
```

Due to *Numpy* **broadcasting** there is no need to use any loop
to operate on consecutive rows.

The result is:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```